# How MySQL works in iOS

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c

Following Question is not for Negative voters, Infect I have to program an iOS app in Objective C, which works with MySQL Database on server side, since app requires to communicate with server(needs user to input few text boxes and to attach in Image).and on the otherside users can track a number to see results(uploaded by other users). hence I am restricted to use json coz json retrieves over all file and then extract required result from that file, 
That's why I needs to use serverside MySQL and needs to run few queries(POST) to submit information provided by users and also needs some query to retrieve required number's row from MySQL Database.

Now the problem is that I am quite unknown from MySQL installation on serverside, and also unfamiliar that how to connect MySQL with my iOS app using Objective C.

Since there are lots of tutorials on the internet forums and as well as at youtube, but I am not able to make final selection that, which tutorial will be the best suitable for me to quick & Detailed learn these things, and Since last two days I am spending my lots of time but still unable to find any easy, quick & Complete tutorial for this purpose.

your quick help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In such kind of applications, their are Web API's / Web Services interface provided by using some server side scripting language coupled with a database, in your case the database is MySql.

> A web service is a collection of open protocols and standards used for
>   exchanging data between applications or systems. Software applications
>   written in various programming languages and running on various
>   platforms can use web services to exchange data over computer networks
>   like the Internet in a manner similar to inter-process communication
>   on a single computer. This interoperability (e.g., between Java and
>   Python, or Windows and Linux applications) is due to the use of open
>   standards.

These web services provide API's in form of some URL's with specific parameters and on the behalf of those parameters it communicate with the database and return some data either in XML or in JSON. And on the behalf of that data the user's app can perform various tasks.

[Web Service Reference](http://www.service-architecture.com/articles/web-services/web_services_explained.html)